# Why Eclipse can't resolve android.support.v7?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

The appcompat-v7 jar is referenced and there is no conflicting libs folder in my project. Still, Eclipse can't resolve android.support.v7. Here's a Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "The appcompat-v7 jar is referenced" -- that is not the way you use most Android library projects in Eclipse. Please follow the [adding libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) instructions for Eclipse, and see if that helps.

Comment: Also consider to change IDE to AS

Comment: Yes, consider changing to Android Studio as it's the officially supported IDE and the dependency management on it is much more automatic.

Comment: Switch to Android Studio